# Java App Error Code 1054 Using JPA and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa, eclipselink

I'm currently working on an application wherein I'm trying to access a local MySQL database, and specifically trying to run the code:

```
DataManagerImpl dm = new DataManagerImpl();
    System.out.println(dm.findJobByCode("ABN54"));
```

As a basic check to see if I can actually query the database. 
This is the start of the OrderTable entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_table")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "OrderTable.findAll", query = "SELECT o FROM OrderTable o")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "OrderTable.findByOrderID", query = "SELECT o FROM OrderTable o WHERE o.orderID = :orderID")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "OrderTable.findByTotalPrice", query = "SELECT o FROM OrderTable o WHERE o.totalPrice = :totalPrice")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "OrderTable.findBySpecialInstructions", query = "SELECT o FROM OrderTable o WHERE o.specialInstructions = :specialInstructions")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "OrderTable.findByStatus", query = "SELECT o FROM OrderTable o WHERE o.status = :status")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "OrderTable.findByPaymentdetailID", query = "SELECT o FROM OrderTable o WHERE o.paymentdetailID = :paymentdetailID")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "OrderTable.findByDateSubmitted", query = "SELECT o FROM OrderTable o WHERE o.dateSubmitted = :dateSubmitted")})
public class OrderTable implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "orderID")
private Integer orderID;
@Column(name = "total_price")
private Float totalPrice;
@Column(name = "special_instructions")
private String specialInstructions;
@Column(name = "status")
private String status;
@Column(name = "payment_detailID")
private String paymentdetailID;
@Column(name = "date_submitted")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dateSubmitted;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "orderTable")
private PaymentDetail paymentDetail;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "orderID")
private Collection<Job> jobCollection;
@JoinColumn(name = "account_no", referencedColumnName = "account_no")
@ManyToOne
private Customer accountNo;
```

And here is the start of my Job class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "job")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Job.findAll", query = "SELECT j FROM Job j")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Job.findByCode", query = "SELECT j FROM Job j WHERE j.code = :code")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Job.findByJobDescription", query = "SELECT j FROM Job j WHERE j.jobDescription = :jobDescription")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Job.findByPrice", query = "SELECT j FROM Job j WHERE j.price = :price")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Job.findByJobDeadline", query = "SELECT j FROM Job j WHERE j.jobDeadline = :jobDeadline")
    , @NamedQuery(name = "Job.findByOrderID", query = "SELECT j FROM Job j WHERE j.orderID = :orderID")})
public class Job implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "code")
private String code;
@Column(name = "job_description")
private String jobDescription;
// @Max(value=?)  @Min(value=?)//if you know range of your decimal fields consider using these annotations to enforce field validation
@Column(name = "price")
private Float price;
@Column(name = "job_deadline")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date jobDeadline;
@JoinColumn(name = "orderID", referencedColumnName = "orderID")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private OrderTable orderID;
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "code")
private Collection<JobLine> jobLineCollection;
```

Here is the error I'm getting from running this.

```
[EL Info]: 2018-03-28 15:40:58.826--ServerSession(1692092775)--EclipseLink, 
version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd
[EL Info]: connection: 2018-03-28 15:40:59.062--ServerSession(1692092775)--file:/E:/Documents/GitHub/Bapers/build/classes/_BapersPU login successful
[EL Warning]: 2018-03-28 15:40:59.139--ServerSession(1692092775)--Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'payment_detailID' in 'field list'
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'payment_detailID' in 'field list'
Error Code: 1054
Call: SELECT orderID, date_submitted, payment_detailID, special_instructions, status, total_price, account_no FROM order_table WHERE (orderID = ?)
Error Code: 1054
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadObjectQuery(name="orderID" referenceClass=OrderTable )
Call: SELECT orderID, date_submitted, payment_detailID, special_instructions, status, total_price, account_no FROM order_table WHERE (orderID = ?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadObjectQuery(name="orderID" referenceClass=OrderTable )
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDetailedException(QueryImpl.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:517)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.getSingleResult(EJBQueryImpl.java:400)
    at data.DataManagerImpl.findJobByCode(DataManagerImpl.java:127)
    at solsoftbapers2.SolSoftBapers2.main(SolSoftBapers2.java:35)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'payment_detailID' in 'field list'
Error Code: 1054
Call: SELECT orderID, date_submitted, payment_detailID, special_instructions, status, total_price, account_no FROM order_table WHERE (orderID = ?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadObjectQuery(name="orderID" referenceClass=OrderTable )
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:682)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2002)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectOneRow(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:714)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectOneRowFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2801)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectOneRow(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2754)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadObjectQuery.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1168)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.execute(ReadObjectQuery.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:3214)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.indirection.NoIndirectionPolicy.valueFromQuery(NoIndirectionPolicy.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRowInternal(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:2294)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.OneToOneMapping.valueFromRowInternal(OneToOneMapping.java:1860)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.valueFromRow(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:2144)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ForeignReferenceMapping.readFromRowIntoObject(ForeignReferenceMapping.java:1471)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildAttributesIntoObject(ObjectBuilder.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:1004)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildWorkingCopyCloneNormally(ObjectBuilder.java:898)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObjectInUnitOfWork(ObjectBuilder.java:851)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:734)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.buildObject(ObjectBuilder.java:688)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.buildObject(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:795)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.registerResultInUnitOfWork(ReadObjectQuery.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadObjectQuery.java:552)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1168)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadObjectQuery.execute(ReadObjectQuery.java:431)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1215)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1804)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1786)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1751)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'payment_detailID' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:383)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1062)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4208)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4140)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2597)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2758)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2826)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2212)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:1007)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:642)
    ... 44 more
C:\Users\Daniel\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

I'm fairly new to using JPA and databases in Java applications, so I imagine I've made a few small mistakes which are the problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `Unknown column 'payment_detailID'`

Comment: I don't understand why Java generated this in the OrderTable class, considering there isn't a single column in the whole database called "payment_detailID"

Comment: How did you generate the entities? It's not like "Java" automatically makes you entities and puts random properties in there.

Comment: It looks like something generated by Netbeans, is it?

Comment: this line needs fixing : `@Column(name = "payment_detailID")`

Comment: Yes it was generated by netbeans: right click package -> entity classes from database.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the payment_detailID query as well as annotations and variable declerations related to it, which seemed to fix the issue (payment_detailID wasn't in the OrderTable as a column in the database).

I then found I was getting another error which seemed to be related to how JPA was building SQL statements and that one of my columns was "City/Town". For some reason it really didn't like the "/" being there. 
So I renamed the column "city" and now it's working fine.